# FDM(frequency division multiplexing) at MAC layer in omnet++

Tags: macos, networking, frequency, omnet++, inet

I need to work on Mac Management sub layer. So that every node will have different frequencies. Suppose node 1 is at frequency one then after some time it switch its frequency. How should i implement it?
I am new to inet and don't know how should i use its modules and .cc files. 
I will be much obliged if anyone will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the current carrier frequency of a node like this

```
auto r = check_and_cast<FlatRadioBase*>(radio);
r->setCarrierFrequency(MHz(2405 + 5*k));
```

The correct frequency of course depends on your physical layer. The one given above is for a IEEE 802.15.4 physical layer, but you should be able to adapt it to other frequency ranges easily.